# For REST, how do I receive posted data using PHP?

Tags: php, rest

I want to set up a tiny RESTful interface for my web services using PHP. The problem is that I looked at frameworks and I cannot figure out how do I recieve the posted data without field names?

For example, if a server posts data to my server, I cannot figure out how do I get it without needing the postfield (POST variables). Traditionally, with forms, people send post data with field names such as this:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postfield=postvalue);
```

and I would use PHP code like this:

```
 $postvalue=$_POST[postfield];
```

to get value of postfield but since the server posting data is not using postfield and is just sending XML, how do I get it without fields? How do I capture the XML? That's where I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@netrox

- it's perfectly valid to use application/x-www-urlencoded for REST services
- you can read any kind of POST data like this:

  ```
  $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
  ```

If your service accepts JSON format you can than decode and use it:

```
$json = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: That's the answer I'm looking for. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

That gives you the raw body that was sent by the client

Answer (score -1):

In general you use either GET or POST to pass data to the server. Depending on what your API is supposed to do, you have to choose one. But every entry should have a key simply because it easier to implement and use. Passing data without keys, in mandatory order (to keep your code know where is what) is error prone.

Answer (score -2):

Every post variable has a name. It doesn't matter where it's coming from. If they are sending XML, that XML data has a name, and you can use $_POST to get the XML data. Once you get XML data you can parse it with an [XML parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Answer (score -2):

u can try this

```
<xml>
<item>
 <something>value</something>
</item>
</xml>
```

since u'r getting the xml... i think now from the curl u get the text and to get the value from  u use this

```
$whatineed = $curlValue->item->something;
```